# Removal of duplicates from specific columns/rows only

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataset with a lot of duplicate TIME and AIR data entries. I need to remove all of the rows that contain these entries. This in itself would be extremely simple:

```
DATE <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3) 
    #Supposed to be 4 entries per date; day 1 has 1 entry too many, day 2 has 2 entries too many
TIME <- c(0,3,3,6,9,0,0,3,6,9,9,0,3,6,9) 
    #Samples are taken every 3 hours from 0-9 each day
AIR <- c(1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4)

DF <- data.frame(DATE, TIME, AIR)

DF1 <- DF[!(duplicated(DF$TIME) & duplicated(DF$AIR)),]
```

`DF1` would output the following:

```
  DATE TIME AIR
1    1    0 1.1
2    1    3 1.2
4    1    6 1.3
5    1    9 1.4
```

However, I need to consider each day, or DATE, individually, the output I am actually looking for is:

```
DATE TIME AIR
1   0   1.1
1   3   1.2
1   6   1.3
1   9   1.4
2   0   1.1
2   3   1.2
2   6   1.3
2   9   1.4
3   0   1.1
3   3   1.2
3   6   1.3
3   9   1.4
```

In this case the duplication stops for each given day. I thought it would be as straightforward as slightly adapting my piece of code, it transpires that it is not, I have tried many variations of: `DF2 <- DF[!(duplicated(DF$TIME) & duplicated(DF$AIR)) & duplicated(DF$DATE),]` to no avail. Therefore it probably requires something slightly more complicated - or at least beyond my current means. Could anyone advise on what I would need to do in order to consider each day seperately in this way? Thank you so much!

Note that in reality it may be that `TIME` is duplicated but `AIR` is not; this is why I have to remove only those entries where `TIME` and `AIR` are duplicates.

Comment: If you don't have any other columns in your data, you can use `unique(DF)`

Comment: Unfortunately my full dataset has about 104 columns

Comment: In that case you can use `DF[!duplicated(DF[,1:3]),]` if those were the first 3 columns. Alternatively, you can specify a character vector of column names to replace `1:3`.

Comment: Except I want to keep duplicate `DATE`, just not `TIME` and `AIR`. But @Sotos answer has worked, thanks anyway though!

Comment: It produces the same result as the one by @Sotos except for the row.names (because of dplyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group, i.e. (with `dplyr`)

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(DATE) %>% 
  filter(!(duplicated(TIME) & duplicated(AIR))
```